# How do I use importtsc with hadoop 2.2 and hbase 1.1.0.1

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hbase, data-migration

From [link](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/21/migrating-data-from-mysql-into-hbase/), I found this command to import data from tsv files in hadoop:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HBASE_HOME/hbase-0.92.1.jar 
   importtsv \-Dim-porttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,t:v01,t:v02,t:v03,t:v04,
   t:v05,t:v06,t:v07,t:v08,t:v09,t:v10,t:v11,t:v12,t:v13,t:v14,t:v15,
   t:v16,t:v17,t:v18,t:v19,t:v20,t:v21,t:v22,t:v23,t:v24 \
hly_temp \ /user/hac/input/2-1
```

But I am using hbase 1.1.0.1, where I am not able to find such jar for hbase as is used in above command. There are lot of jars in `hbase/lib` folder, but when I use those (`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HBASE_HOME/lib/*`),  I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/local/hbase/lib/hbase-annotations-1/1/0/1/jar
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Comment: Please dont use 0.92 version. Its tooo old. current release is 1.1

Comment: @AnilGupta, Yes thats what I am trying to use, 0.92  was being used in the link I am referring, I am using  1.1.0.1.

Comment: Then why are you still referencing "hbase-0.92.1.jar" in question? I think, in this post you need to clearly specify the command that you are running.

Comment: @AnilGupta: Actually I didnt found any good guide with this new version. Let me know if you have any leads.